# VBA - Transferring (other than values) bypassing Clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code within the script.

My issue is, within `wb.ws.range` i have certain columns which contain numbers such as 00100. These values are being copied across as 100 rather than 00100.

I suspect it's very simple... but can't find the answer anywhere

```
With wb.ws.Range(Range( _
                      Range("A3"), _
                      Range("A3").End(xlDown) _
                      ), _
                Range( _
                      Range("R3"), _
                      Range("R3").End(xlDown) _
                      ) _
                .End(xlToRight) _
                )
Mwb.Mws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value2
End With
```

Comment: You will want to also set the `.NumberFormat` property for the columns you want formatted like `#####` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat

Comment: A number has never leading `0` - only it's format. You simply need to set the number format of the destination cell

Comment: is there a way of keeping the original sheets format - as there are multiple columns with different format types

Comment: Use the `PasteSpecial` command for that https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial. In your case, you want to have a look to the Paste-Type `xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats`

Comment: If you aren't using the numbers for calculations, you can look at forcing the numbers as text by preceeding the value with an apostrophe `'`. This means where you would type `00100` into a cell and it changes to `100`, if you type `'00100` it forces it as a text value. It does mean you can't perform any calculations however as excel does not recognise it as a numeric value.

Comment: @FunThomas - there are two issues with this 1) it requires the clipboard, which is inefficient. 2) i have a lot of hidden rows which also require to be copied across

Comment: @SamuelEverson - how would i define that in my script?

Comment: The use of `wb.ws.range(...)` looks incorrect. Could you share the complete code? If you have done `Set wb = ...`  and `Set ws = wb.Worksheets(...)`, then in the continuation of the code you have to use just `ws.Range(...)`.

Comment: Could you share the column numbers (strings) that contain the critical numbers and clarify if they are text or just numbers with a certain number format?

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust the number format for a Column with:

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "0000#"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `PasteSpecial` is the fastest (and easiest) way to copy more than the pure content (value) in Excel. As long as you copy only one (or few) ranges you will have no speed problem. It gets inefficient if you loop over a large range and then use copy&paste every single time. Just did a test with 20.000 rows * 8 columns and the use of `PasteSpecial` worked instantly.

Alternative would be to loop over every single cell to assign the `numberformat`, and this would be much more inefficient.

As you wrote in the comments that you want to copy also data from hidden rows: Using PasteSpecial, all data from your range will be copied, no matter if there are hidden rows or columns.

Note that your definition of the source range is strange, and it is flawed. It will work only if `ws` is the current sheet - the `Range`-part inside the brackets will look to ActiveSheet, not to `ws`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer - 

Please may you edit your answer to provide the example code you ran?? I have attempted a ```PasteSpecial```, however, my hidden rows seem to not be included. 

Thanks for the extra note - i have now updated to explicitly define the sheet ```ws``` for each Range.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Values by Assignment

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- This covers how to get (create a reference to) the relevant range, how you could change the number format to text (for the whole range), and how to remove (`ClearContents`) the possible remaining old data in the relevant columns of the destination worksheet.
- Feel free to inquire about other details in the comments below.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copyValuesByAssignment()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sCols As String = "A:R"
    Const sFirstRow As Long = 3
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim srg As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Columns(sCols).Rows(sFirstRow)
        Dim sCell As Range
        Set sCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set srg = .Resize(sCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst).Resize(, srg.Columns.Count)
        .Resize(srCount).NumberFormat = "@" ' or just for some columns?
        .Resize(srCount).Value = srg.Value
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - srCount + 1) _
            .Offset(srCount).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```